# TypeError: 'sage.rings.integer.Integer' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, sage

I am trying to implement differential cryptanalysis on an sbox for a DES algorithm, and I'm receiving this error.
This is my code so far:

```
s1=[14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7,
0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8,
4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0,
15, 12, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, 11, 3, 14, 10, 0, 6, 13]
b=[]
for i in range(0, 63):
    j=ZZ(i).binary().zfill(6)
    b += [s1[ZZ('0b'+j[0]+j[5])][ZZ('0b'+j[1]+j[2]+j[3]+j[4])]]
s1=mq.SBox(b)
ddt=s1.difference_distribution_matrix()
for i in range(63):
    print i,ddt[i]
```

The error is on

```
b += [s1[ZZ('0b'+j[0]+j[5])][ZZ('0b'+j[1]+j[2]+j[3]+j[4])]]
```

Comment: And the error is on which line?

Comment: Please provide the full traceback in your question.

Comment: The error is on "b += [s1[ZZ('0b'+j[0]+j[5])][ZZ('0b'+j[1]+j[2]+j[3]+j[4])]]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s1 is a list of a single dimension.

s1[ZZ('0b'+j[0]+j[5])][ZZ('0b'+j[1]+j[2]+j[3]+j[4])] is trying to index into the return of an index.

s1[ZZ('0b'+j[0]+j[5])] pulls back the integer value in s1 is position [ZZ('0b'+j[0]+j[5])].

Then you are trying to index into the integer at position [ZZ('0b'+j[1]+j[2]+j[3]+j[4])].

That is my best guess without knowing what is happening in ZZ().

Comment: `ZZ` is just a coercion to arbitrary length integers in SageMath, so that methods available to that class (but not to Python `int`s) are there.